# Templated serialization of C# objects to JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json

I need to serialize objects to JSON. I would like to do it with a **template** instead of using data annotations (as most frameworks do). Does anybody know a good way of doing this?

A picture says more than 1000 words. I'm looking for something that looks like this:

[image]

For example, if I had a class like this:

```
public class Test  
{ 
    public string Key { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Code { get; set; } 
    public Test Related { get; set; } 
}
```

And a had template string that *could* look like this:

```
{ 
    id: "$Key",
    name: "$Name",
    related: "$Related.Name"
}
```

I want to get a JSON object, whose properties are filled in according to `Key`, `Name` and `Related.Name` of the object.

Basically I'm searching for a **JSON serialization** method that **supports templating** instead.

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly do you want. Do you want to create a method that has that template hard-coded and works on any type that has `Key`, `Name` and `Related.Name`? Or do you want a complete system that can understand templates in the format you specified and serialize using them?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker No one is required to explain downvotes, as downvoting is anonymous.  Additionally, this question doesn't show any research effort and is incredibly vague (and can be argued is not constructive as well since you're basically asking for a list of products/items).

Comment: @casperOne, I disagree that this question is not constructive. It asks how to do one specific thing. I think it can be reasonably answered in a way that fits SO, at least in the current form. (I edited the template sample back in and tried to explain it more.)

Comment: @casperOne a little more explanation please? How could I improve this question?

Comment: @svick The key there being, *in it's current form* which you've edited to make it *less broad*, etc., etc.  In other words, you performed an edit to make the question, people are voting to reopen, the system works.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker The edit that svick performed is a step in the right direction.  Additionally, your question boils down to this "I would like to use this handler for more than one type of object, so I would like to use a template to do the serialization. Does anyone know a way to do this?" - that's a "gimme teh codez" question, to which people often reply with *what have you tried*?

Comment: @casperOne I removed the handler from the question, because that was only some context. I'm looking for a serializer! The stuf svick put there was from my previous edit, but I thought it was confusing the people.

Comment: The "Not constructive" part seems a bit harsh...

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker You have to realize that you're still asking a very broad question (see prior comment) and that's the root of the problem.  Again, if people feel this is worth opening, then they will vote to open it.  Moderator closures are reversible.

Comment: I'm curious why a template engine is desired when you can simply create an anonymous type and serialize that object. It has limitations - you have little control over how the values are formatted, but it works quite well.

Comment: I have a asp.net handler that retrieves objects. Those objects need to be serialized to JSON so I can use them in JQuery. My design time objects and the information that is retrieved from them may differ when the system is used over time. As different scenarios may unfold I would like to be able to serialize more or less information without having to recompile the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 years have passed since I've posted the question. Since I've been working with Node.JS and discovered Handlebars and how it is pretty easy to get it to parse JSON instead of HTML template. [The Handlebars project has been converted to .NET.](https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net)

You can use a special `ITextEncoder` to let Handlebars generate JSON:

```cs
using HandlebarsDotNet;
using System.Text;

public class JsonTextEncoder : ITextEncoder
{
    public void Encode(StringBuilder text, TextWriter target)
    {
        Encode(text.ToString(), target);
    }

    public void Encode(string text, TextWriter target)
    {
        if (text == null || text == "") return;
        text = System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(text);
        target.Write(text);
    }

    public void Encode<T>(T text, TextWriter target) where T : IEnumerator<char>
    {
        var str = text?.ToString();
        if (str == null) return;

        Encode(str, target);
    }
}
```

Let's see it in action:

```cs
using HandlebarsDotNet;

var handlebars = Handlebars.Create();
handlebars.Configuration.TextEncoder = new JsonTextEncoder();

var sourceTemplate = @"{ 
    ""id"": ""{{Key}}"",
    ""name"": ""{{Name}}"",
    ""related "": ""{{Related.Name}}""
}";

var template = handlebars.Compile(sourceTemplate);

var json = template(new
{
    Key = "Alpha",
    Name = "Beta",
    Related = new
    {
        Name = "Gamme"
    }
});

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

This will write the following:

```
{
    "id": "Alpha",
    "name": "Beta",
    "related ": "Gamme"
}
```

I did a small write-up on the topic on my blog: [Handlebars.Net & JSON templates](https://keestalkstech.com/2022/09/handlebars-net-json-templates/). In this blog I also discuss how to improve debugging these templates.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know about any library that does this for you, but it's not that hard to build it yourself.

If you have your template, you need to parse it as JSON and then replace all of the placeholders with actual values. To do that, you can use the visitor pattern.

Since JSON.NET (the JSON library I'm using) doesn't seem to have a visitor, you can create one yourself:

```
abstract class JsonVisitor
{
    public virtual JToken Visit(JToken token)
    {
        var clone = token.DeepClone();
        return VisitInternal(clone);
    }

    protected virtual JToken VisitInternal(JToken token)
    {
        switch (token.Type)
        {
        case JTokenType.Object:
            return VisitObject((JObject)token);
        case JTokenType.Property:
            return VisitProperty((JProperty)token);
        case JTokenType.Array:
            return VisitArray((JArray)token);
        case JTokenType.String:
        case JTokenType.Integer:
        case JTokenType.Float:
        case JTokenType.Date:
        case JTokenType.Boolean:
        case JTokenType.Null:
            return VisitValue((JValue)token);
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }

    protected virtual JToken VisitObject(JObject obj)
    {
        foreach (var property in obj.Properties())
            VisitInternal(property);

        return obj;
    }

    protected virtual JToken VisitProperty(JProperty property)
    {
        VisitInternal(property.Value);

        return property;
    }

    protected virtual JToken VisitArray(JArray array)
    {
        foreach (var item in array)
            VisitInternal(item);

        return array;
    }

    protected virtual JToken VisitValue(JValue value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And then create a specialized visitor that replaces the placeholders with actual values:

```
class JsonTemplateVisitor : JsonVisitor
{
    private readonly object m_data;

    private JsonTemplateVisitor(object data)
    {
        m_data = data;
    }

    public static JToken Serialize(object data, string templateString)
    {
        return Serialize(
            data, (JToken)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(templateString));
    }

    public static JToken Serialize(object data, JToken template)
    {
        var visitor = new JsonTemplateVisitor(data);

        return visitor.Visit(template);
    }

    protected override JToken VisitValue(JValue value)
    {
        if (value.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            var s = (string)value.Value;

            if (s.StartsWith("$"))
            {
                string path = s.Substring(1);

                var newValue = GetValue(m_data, path);

                var newValueToken = new JValue(newValue);

                value.Replace(newValueToken);

                return newValueToken;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    private static object GetValue(object data, string path)
    {
        var parts = path.Split('.');

        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            if (data == null)
                break;

            data = data.GetType()
                .GetProperty(part)
                .GetValue(data, null);
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

The usage is then simple. For example, with the following template:

```
{ 
    id : "$Key",
    name: "$Name",
    additionalInfo:
    {
        related: [ "$Related.Name" ]
    }
}
```

You can use code like this:

```
JsonTemplateVisitor.Serialize(data, templateString)
```

The result then looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "someKey",
  "name": "Isaac",
  "additionalInfo": {
    "related": [
      "Arthur"
    ]
  }
}
```

You might want to add some error-checking, but other than that, the code should work. Also, it uses reflection, so it might not be suitable if performance is important.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow. Looks promising! Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same need. I needed an end user (technical users but not developers) to be able to create their own json files that can later be filled via data.

Microsoft Teams is doing something similar with their adaptive card website:
https://adaptivecards.io/designer/

On the bottom left there is a json "template" and on the bottom right a json to load into the template.

Conclusion: Despite extensive research **I have not found any .NET library doing this.**

Sorry (๑•́ㅿ•̀๑).

[Screenshot of adaptive card designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzwrF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Text Template file for your json template . The template engine will fill in the blanks and return you the result.
If you are using Visual Studio,

1. Create a **.tt** file ,
2. Mark it with **TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor** in Custom Tool property of the file. This will create a new class for you that takes care of processing the template.
3. For integrating your data in the resulted string , extend the newly generated class in a separate file , in which you pass the data (the arbitrary class from you image).
4. Use this to get the json formatted code;

   ```
   MyData data = ...;  
   MyTemplatePage page = new MyTemplatePage(data);  
   String pageContent = page.TransformText();
   ```

Now the pageContent have the json formatted string; For more details about how to handle the .tt file , look here : [Text Template Control Blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126545.aspx)